# Cannot log to the local Mysql Server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed XAMPP. I had put up security barriers but as time went by I forgot my credentials and could no longer access the MySQL server through phpMyAdmin. I keep having the following error trying to enter phpMyAdmin:

> 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.

I've edited C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc to change my passwords but I had no success afterwards. I've altered the bit:

```
Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'xxxxx' ;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yyyy' ;
```

I've run the MySQL resetroot batch file without success.

I've changed the default ports on my Apache and Mysql at the localhost a couple weeks ago and now I can't access mysql.exe.

> Can't connect to MYSQL service on 'localhost'(10061).

How can I change the default localhost port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/)?

> After installing a local server and trying to access phpMyAdmin, you could possibly encounter the error: #1045 Access Denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
>
> If root@localhost wasn't granted the necessary rights to access the database or you provided the wrong password, you will then encounter this error.
>
> Following this tutorial will help guide you on bypassing this error, for any local host server using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I have not, but I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've tried and I think I know where the error may be coming from. I've change the default ports on my Apache and Mysql at the localhost a couple weeks ago and now I can't access mysql.exe. It says: Can't connect to MYSQL service on 'localhost'(10061). How can I change the default localhost port? Do you think that may be the problem? Thanks in advance!